# Custom keyboard variant not selectable

Tags: gnome, xorg, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to make a custom keyboard variant for Ubuntu 17.10 with default gnome (Xorg).

In file /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/be I added the text below:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "r03" {

    include "be(basic)"
    name[Group1]="Belgian (r03)";

    key <TLDE>  { [ at, threesuperior, onesuperior, lessthanequal ] };

};
```

There will be more changes, but this is a test. The key above tab should be '@'.
(My complete layout is available here: https://github.com/roelandmoors/azerty#installing-on-linux)

I also changed /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml to add this new variant to the 'be' layout:

```
<variant>
  <configItem>
    <name>r03</name>
    <description>Belgian (r03)</description>
  </configItem>
</variant>
```

The folder /var/lib/xkb only contains a readme.

When I use `setxkbmap -layout be -variant r03` the new keymap seems to work fine.

The problem is that I can't select the new variant when I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. In the gnome settings I can't even select a variant. I tried with the dconf editor to change `/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/sources` to `[('xkb', 'be+r03')]` but then I get a querty layout instead of azerty. (fallback if settings is wrong?)

How can I make my new layout selectable in the settings. I want this as my default keyboard layout (also in gdm).

**Update:**

I got `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` working, but it is very uggly. (don't do it, just edit /etc/default/keyboard)

Copy the output of this command:

```
sudo /usr/share/console-setup/kbdnames-maker /usr/share/console-setup/KeyboardNames.pl | grep r03
```

I should be something like this: `C*variant*be*r03*Belgian - Belgian (r03)`

Then add this line to this file: (search for similar lines)

```
sudo vi /var/lib/dpkg/info/keyboard-configuration.config
```

Now you can select the new variant in `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

Comment: Did you reboot after having made the changes?

Comment: yes, but that didn't help.

Comment: I added the above snippets to my 17.10, and it works fine for me. Found in GNOME settings under "French (Belgium)".

Comment: Could you make a screenshot or something? I don't have French (Belgium) only Belgian.

Comment: I found it, I changed org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources back to the default and changed my regional format settings to the correct value. After a reboot I could choose the new variant. Thanks!

Comment: Great that you figured it out. I posted an answer to cover the last part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual way to make the custom layout available on the login screen is to edit the `/etc/default/keyboard` file. Assuming that it currently includes these two lines:

```
XKBLAYOUT="be"
XKBVARIANT=""
```

you can e.g. change them to read:

```
XKBLAYOUT="be,be"
XKBVARIANT="r03,"
```

After next reboot, a keyboard layout indicator should be visible allowing you to choose betweeen *Belgian (r03)* and *Belgian*. Probably the former willl be preselected.

Comment: Thx, that works as you describe. I think this could also be done with `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, but there I can't select my new layout variant.

Comment: @r03: I suspect that the reason is that you didn't edit the `evdev.lst` file too. But it's a guess; didn't test.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. It looks like the program reads xorg.xml. https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/d-i/console-setup.git/tree/Keyboard/xmlreader  But it's OK. I changed the default keyboard file and it works.

Comment: @r03: `xorg.xml` is a symlink pointing to `base.xml`, so then maybe copying the modified `evdev.xml` to `base.xml` would make a difference (for some reason they both exist on Ubuntu and they are identical).

Comment: That didn't work. I added an uggly fix in my answer.

Comment: @r03: Thanks for the research! This is apparently a complex topic.

Answer (score 2):

To make the custom layout selectable also on the login screen, you can go to *Settings -> Region & Language*, click the *Login Screen* button at the top right of the window, and add it there as well.

[image]

Comment: I don't see that button? https://ibb.co/hzP4Sb

Comment: @r03: I can't see it on that screenshot either. Is your system updated? `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: @r03: Hmm.. I'm confused, and filed [bug #1730900](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1730900).

Comment: @r03: For the sake of completeness: The "Login Screen" button is showed only if you have more than one user accounts on the system.  Compare [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/975995).