# how to set keyboard layout at login? ubuntu 17.10

Tags: login, keyboard-layout

Recently upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10 and I can't seem to find a way to set my keyboard layout at the new login screen. I have set the input method to dvorak within the settings>region+language option, and it works fine when logged in, but whenever I log out it defaults to qwerty and I have to bring up the on screen keyboard to input my password.

Anyone know how to set this properly?

Answer (score 3):

If your changes are not effective for the login screen too, you have probably more than one user account on the system. But in that case, the *Settings -> Region & Language* window includes a "Login Screen" button. Clicking that button switches the mode, so you can control the login screen values separately.

[image]

Comment: I only have the one user account on this system, and do not have that button in my settings.

Comment: @cgate: Then are you sure that the settings you made from the GUI were not already effective on the login screen? Did you reboot to check?

Comment: Correct, changes made within the GUI were ineffective after both logout and reboot. I have fixed it using your CLI method above though.

Comment: @cgate: Ok, thanks. I'd like to understand why...

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the codes of the desired language layouts in the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst` file under the section named ! layout.
2. Use the `localectl` tool to change the system keyboard layout settings as follows:

   localectl set-x11-keymap layout
3. Log out to find that the defined layouts are available at the top bar on the login screen.

For more information check [here](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/keyboard-layout.html.en).

Comment: Tried this, using the command 

"localectl set-x11-keymap dvorak"

found no change at login screen, still qwerty only.

Comment: @cgate: Try this: `localectl set-x11-keymap us,us pc105 dvorak,` (I have to say that the linked docs page is not complete.)

Comment: This has done the trick. Thanks. 

Would you mind explaining what the "us,us pc105" part does though? does dvorak need to be defined as a subset of the us layout?

Comment: @cgate: I'd suggest that you look at the `/etc/default/keyboard` file to study the result of the command. As you can see there, `dvorak` is a variant of the `us` layout. You can also run `man localectl` to see the documentation of the `localectl` command.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but recently I have faced with the same issue.

During the Linux Mint installation, I accidentally selected the wrong keyboard layout. Later I fixed it by removing the old one and adding the proper keyboard, but unfortunately, this had no impact on the login screen.

Solution:

1. login and show your current, working layout configuration with `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10`
2. check the layout that is used on the login screen: `cat /etc/default/keyboard`
3. set up properly the login screen keyboard layout with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

That was the only solution that worked for me.
I hope that it helps you as well.