# Changing keyboard layout without logging in to any user in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, login, keyboard-layout, language-support

I mistakenly removed the "English" keyboard layout from the keyboard layouts list while trying to delete the keyboard layout of another language. Just afterwards, my device froze, and I decided to restart after a while. Big mistake, as I realized, that I could not login to my user account anymore, since the keyboard layout existing currently is not in English, but the password of my main user has English letters. I am using Ubuntu 17.10. Now, is there anyway I could bring back the English keyboard layout from the login screen, without typing a single latin alphabet anywhere, so that I could login again?

Comment: This to me appears to be a complex issue requiring a number of answers although you've phrased the question quite clearly. Give me a minute...

Answer (score 1):

Steps 1 through 6 of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/165248/225694) should get you into the system since grub knows nothing about your installed keyboard layouts. Then follow up with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/975957/225694) and read the comments too as they will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to make en layout on login, then configure layouts in system settings.
You should change `etc/default/keyboard` in recovery mode or from live cd/usb.
Full explanation [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1135720/449979)

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to toggle the on-screen keyboard available on the top-right menu, click on the little flag key, and adding/switching to english input method.