# Keyboard layout stuck into CZ_german no english layout after update, restore into original EN_us and EL_Gr ones

Tags: kde, keyboard-layout, input-language

After Update on Kubuntu 16.04LTS the keyboard layout has changed into CZ_german without any english layout. Thus I want to restore it into US,GR variant.

Due to unexpected keyboard layout change I find it hard to login either via shell or Xorg. Thus the only option is to use either the recovery mode or a live USB.

Thus how I can revocer the keyboard layout into English and Greek one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boot from a live usb and mount the disk that has the GNU/Linux Installed, keep in mind to mount the partition having the **INSTALLED** system's root filesystem (and not the root folder from the liveusb distro).

In my case has been the /dev/sda2 and I mounted as:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

Using the command `sudo fdisk -l` and judging from the size and the type (correct one `Linux Filesystem`) you can mount the appropriate partition. In case of a wrongly mounted partition you can unmount it via the command (we are using the `cd` command as well in order to make not busy the mounted partition):

```
cd && sudo umount /mnt
```

Also In the mounted partition should containe the `etc` folder as well.

Having said that now you can nou type the following command:

```
sudo nano /mnt/etc/default/keyboard
```

And from:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="a4techKB21"
XKBLAYOUT="cz"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Change it into:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="a4techKB21"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

In case that the change has been into a desktop session that you are already logeedin then edit the `/etc/default/keyboard` directly (as long as you are able to locate the correct layout on the CZ_german layout.)

Save the file and then reboot. Once you login configure the keyboard layout via these steps:

First of all go to "System Settings" as the following Images show (System Language In Greek):
[image: Select settings Step 1]
[image: Select Settings Step 2]

On the opened window then select "Input Devices" (in Greek "Συσκευές Εισόδου") as seen In the following Image:

[image: Select Input Devices]

Afterwards select Keyboard and click on the icons as seen in the following image (with the particular order):
[image: Enable Input Methods]

Afterwards select to Change the layout using `Alt`+`Shift` following the instructions shown in this image:

[image]

So now you have restored the input languages back to Greek and English. Similar steps can be followed to restore into any desired layout.

The whole idea behind it is to first setup into basic `us` layout via any GNU/Linux live usb/cd, then install any localized layout.